# Add background property without overwriting the existing one

Tags: css

I have an issue with CSS.

I have a gradient, with more than one instruction to make it compatible with any browser.

```
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#111111));
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png"), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png"), -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #111111);
```

As you can see, there is also an image for the background. Now, imagine if this image was inline. It would be an enormous waste of space to copy and paste it many times.

Is there a way to do sometning like this:

```
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png");
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #111111);
```

But without overwriting (and destroying) the first property (image) with the second call (gradient)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to repeat yourself use CSS variable:

```css
:root {
 --image:url("https://lorempixel.com/400/200/") center/100px no-repeat 
}

.box {
  height:200px;
  background: var(--image), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#111111));
  background: var(--image), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
  background: var(--image), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
  background: var(--image), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
  background: var(--image), -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #111111);
  background: var(--image), linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #111111);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box" style="--image:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/) center/100px no-repeat ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `:after` psuedo-element to add the gradient on top the image background.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center center url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #111111);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `linear-gradient` and `url` affect the `background-image`, so no, you cannot use those two in conjunction; the second one would overwrite the first.

When you combine these two rules in the following shorthand order:

```
background: no-repeat 20px center url("./img/pc.png");
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #111111);
```

**Only** the `background-image` of the second rule gets applied; the other rules from the first shorthand rule get ignored:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(17, 17, 17));
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
```

**However**, you **can** cause these additional rules to apply by specifying the gradient as the `background-image` manually:

```
background-image: url(./img/pc.png); /* Only rule to get overriden */
background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(17, 17, 17));
background-position-x: 20px;
background-position-y: center;
background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
```

This way your `background-position-x`, `background-position-y`, `background-repeat-x` and `background-repeat-y` rules can be applied in conjunction with your gradient... though it is impossible to have both of your `background-url` rules apply to the same element at the same time.

To have both the image and the gradient show up, I would recommend making use of two elements positioned on top of each other with `position: absolute`, and applying one `background-image` to each. The gradient would go on top, and be **transparent** so that the background image can be seen.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.background {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100");
}

.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #111111);
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="gradient"></div>
```